# SQL BETWEEN datetime

Tags: sql, postgresql

Добрый день,

есть SQL запрос

```
SELECT
  movements.shipment_id,
  movements.location_id,
  string_agg(movements.status_code, ',') AS statuses,
  max(movements.moved_at) AS monitoring_start_time,
  (max(movements.moved_at) + '3 day') AS monitoring_deadline,
  NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS monitoring_now_time
FROM
  movements
INNER JOIN
  shipments
ON
  shipments.id = movements.shipment_id
INNER JOIN
  airports
ON
  airports.id = movements.location_id
WHERE
  shipments.controlled = true
AND
  airports.movements_update_method = 'web'
AND
  movements.location_id IS NOT NULL
AND
  monitoring_now_time BETWEEN monitoring_start_time AND monitoring_deadline
GROUP BY
  movements.shipment_id,
  movements.location_id
```

в `AND monitoring_now_time BETWEEN monitoring_start_time AND monitoring_deadline` я хочу проверить входит ли текущая дата и время во временной промежуток между датами `start_time` и `deadline`

но на все эти три алиаса я получаю ошибки:

```
column "monitoring_now_time" does not exist
column "monitoring_start_time" does not exist
column "monitoring_deadline" does not exist

ERROR:  column "monitoring_now_time" does not exist
LINE 25:   monitoring_now_time BETWEEN monitoring_start_time AND moni...
           ^

********** Ошибка **********

ERROR: column "monitoring_now_time" does not exist
SQL-состояние: 42703
Символ: 550
```

так выглядит результат запроса без `AND monitoring_now_time BETWEEN monitoring_start_time AND monitoring_deadline`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, что бы алиасы для полей тоже учитывались??

Comment: `AND NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' BETWEEN max(movements.moved_at) AND  (max(movements.moved_at) + '3 day')` так работает?

Comment: Так делал уже, не работает

Comment: Какая ошибка приходит в этом случае? Насколько я помню, те данные, которые получаем в select не получится использовать в where. Т.е. на `select 1 as one where one = 1;` получим ошибку `ERROR:  column "one" does not exist`

Comment: получаю aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Алиасы из списка выборки или групповые функции не могут использоваться в предложении where, т.к. оно отрабатывает *до* группировки и формирования списка выборки. Данные условия можно проверять в предложении `having` или надо оборачивать запрос во внешний и уже в нем проверять

```
SELECT movements.shipment_id,
       movements.location_id,
       string_agg(movements.status_code, ',') AS statuses,
       max(movements.moved_at) AS monitoring_start_time,
       (max(movements.moved_at) + '3 day') AS monitoring_deadline,
       NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS monitoring_now_time
  FROM movements
 INNER JOIN shipments ON shipments.id = movements.shipment_id
 INNER JOIN airports  ON airports.id = movements.location_id
 WHERE shipments.controlled = true AND airports.movements_update_method = 'web'
   AND movements.location_id IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY movements.shipment_id, movements.location_id
HAVING NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' BETWEEN max(movements.moved_at)
   AND (max(movements.moved_at) + '3 day')
```

или:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT ..., max(movements.moved_at) AS monitoring_start_time,
                    (max(movements.moved_at) + '3 day') AS monitoring_deadline,
                    NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS monitoring_now_time
          FROM ...
         GROUP BY ...
       ) X
  WHERE monitoring_now_time BETWEEN monitoring_start_time AND monitoring_deadline
```